Issues with nginx configuration for serving two ASP.NET Core apps on the same domain
`I have two ASP.NET Core web applications, each with its own wwwroot directory where CSS, JS, and other libraries are located. The first app (127.0.0.1:5000) correctly uses its own wwwroot, but the second app ends up using the wwwroot of the first app.
I have a single domain (www.xxlgastro.online) and I want to avoid using subdomains. Initially, I assumed I could differentiate the applications by running them on different ports, but this approach doesn't work as expected.
Here are my nginx.conf and default configuration files:
`
#nginx.conf 
events {
  
}

http {
    include        /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=5r/s;
    server_tokens  off;

    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout   29;
    client_body_timeout 10; 
    client_header_timeout 10; 
    send_timeout 10;

    upstream xxlGastro {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    }

    upstream xxlGastro_API {
        server 127.0.0.1:5001;
    } 

    server {
        listen                    443 ssl http2;
        listen                    [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name               example.com *.example.com;
        ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxlgastro.online/fullchain.pem; 
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxlgastro.online/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout       1d;
        ssl_protocols             TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
        ssl_ciphers               ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
        ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets       off;
        ssl_stapling              off;

        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://xxlGastro;
            limit_req  zone=one burst=10 nodelay;
        }
        
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://xxlGastro_API;
            limit_req zone=one burst=10 nodelay;
        }
    }
}

#default site available file
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.xxlgastro.online;  

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;    
    }
    
    location /api/ {
       proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5001;
       proxy_http_version  1.1;
       proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header    Connection keep-alive;
       proxy_set_header    Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxlgastro.online/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxlgastro.online/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;    # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.xxlgastro.online) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    server_name www.xxlgastro.online;
    return 404;
}

